# Use Google Map V3 API ClientID in Application with no URL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

Need to get Google Map V3 API work in my application with purchased ClientID.

The application is using WebBrowser Control to load html into documentText and the Url is 'about:blank'. The problem is I can't put about:blank into authorized URLs list in google map console. Also I can't host html as it needs a lot of data from database. It must be in application. Can anyone help me how to use google map clientID in application? Thanks a lot.

> Error: This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. This URL
>   is not authorized to use the provided Google Maps Client ID. Error
>   Code: UnauthorizedURLForClientIdMapError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got support from google. To use Client ID this way, they actually have to manually add 'about:blank' into white list.

Answer (score 0):

`about:blank` is not a URL, it is in some sense the absence or a URL. In fact, loading the API from `about:blank` does not send a referer header, and `window.location` in `about:blank` is empty.

What this means is that you cannot restrict your client id to a specific URL whitelist if you intend to use the API in this way. This would, however, mean that your client id could be used from any host.

Comment: Correct. Is there any way to trick web browser control to use http://localhost/ as url but use html in code? Because I can add http://localhost/ into white list.

Comment: Got support from google. To use Client ID this way, they actually have to manually add 'about:blank' into white list.